# AngularJS ng-model strange behavior

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I have a simple input with an ng-model to get the value of the input, here is my code :

```
angular
.module('thermofluor')
.directive('tm', tm)

tm.$inject = ['$timeout', '$q', '$rootScope', 'EVENTS'];

function tm($timeout, $q, $rootScope, EVENTS) {
var directive = {
    link: link,
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'tm.html',
    scope: {
        hideTm : '=',
        canSaveTm: '='
    }
};

return directive;

function link(scope, element) {

    scope.calculateTm = calculateTm;
    scope.deleteTm = deleteTm;
    scope.saveTm = saveTm;

    scope.comment = "";

    /**
     * Broadcast a EVENTS.CALCULATE_TM
     */
    function calculateTm(){
        console.log('Broadcast CALCULATE_TM ..');
        $rootScope.$broadcast(EVENTS.CALCULATE_TM);
    }

    /**
     * Broadcast a EVENTS.DELETE_TM
     */
    function deleteTm(){
        console.log('Broadcast DELETE_TM ..');
        $rootScope.$broadcast(EVENTS.DELETE_TM);
    }

    /**
     * Broadcast a EVENTS.SAVE_TM
     */
    function saveTm(){
        console.log('Broadcast SAVE_TM ..');
        $rootScope.$broadcast(EVENTS.SAVE_TM, scope.comment);
    }
  }
}
```

And in the html template I have this :

```
 <input ng-model="comment" class="form-control" type="text" id="tm-comment" name="tm-comment" placeholder="Comment"/>
 <p>{{ comment }}</p>
```

The ng-model seems works fine, when I change the text in the input the paragraph under change too, but when I click on the button who throw the saveTm() function, in the function my values is the default one (""), and for example if the default was "test" the value in the function will be "test", even if I change it in the input.

Why ?

Comment: is the `link` function part of some directive or something similar? if it is, please post all of the code so we can see at least how `scope` is passed.

Comment: Yes it's a directive, but the scope.comment is created here, I edit with all the code

Comment: try this: `scope: { hideTm : '=', canSaveTm: '=', comment: '=' }`

Comment: Doesn't change, the scope here is to pass the variable from the html who call the directive

Comment: this part of the HTML you've posted is part of the directive?

Comment: Yes this is the template of the directive, the thing strange is that the ng-model works, but in the function the value is the default one

Answer (score 1):

I created a simple snippet trying to reproduce your problem, but it seems to work fine. Maybe you have a bug elsewhere (catching/processing broadcasted event).

```js
// Code goes here

angular
.module('thermofluor', [])
.constant('EVENTS', {
  CALCULATE_TM: 'CALCULATE_TM',
  DELETE_TM: 'DELETE_TM',
  SAVE_TM: 'SAVE_TM'
})
.controller('AppController', AppController)
.directive('tm', tm)

AppController.$inject = ['$rootScope', 'EVENTS']

function AppController($rootScope, EVENTS) {
  var ctrl= this;
  $rootScope.$on(EVENTS.SAVE_TM, function(event, val) {
    console.log('$on SAVE_TM', val);
    ctrl.passed = val;
  })
}

tm.$inject = ['$timeout', '$q', '$rootScope', 'EVENTS'];

function tm($timeout, $q, $rootScope, EVENTS) {
var directive = {
    link: link,
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<input ng-model="comment" class="form-control" type="text" id="tm-comment" name="tm-comment" placeholder="Comment"/><p>{{ comment }}</p><button type="button" ng-click="saveTm()">Save Tm</button>',
    scope: {
        hideTm : '=',
        canSaveTm: '='
    }
};

return directive;

function link(scope, element) {

    scope.calculateTm = calculateTm;
    scope.deleteTm = deleteTm;
    scope.saveTm = saveTm;

    scope.comment = "";

    /**
     * Broadcast a EVENTS.CALCULATE_TM
     */
    function calculateTm(){
        console.log('Broadcast CALCULATE_TM ..');
        $rootScope.$broadcast(EVENTS.CALCULATE_TM);
    }

    /**
     * Broadcast a EVENTS.DELETE_TM
     */
    function deleteTm(){
        console.log('Broadcast DELETE_TM ..');
        $rootScope.$broadcast(EVENTS.DELETE_TM);
    }

    /**
     * Broadcast a EVENTS.SAVE_TM
     */
    function saveTm(){
        console.log('Broadcast SAVE_TM ..');
        $rootScope.$broadcast(EVENTS.SAVE_TM, scope.comment);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="thermofluor">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.7.0" data-semver="1.7.0" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.7.0/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="AppController as appCtrl">
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <p ng-if="!!appCtrl.passed">Passed to app controller: {{appCtrl.passed}}</p>
    <tm></tm>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I really still don't know why it's not working, so what I do is put the variable inside the function call in the directive HTML